# How do I display text and other objects in vertical UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

How I display in vertical scrolling only different objects? The pattern should be: Title (Label), Subtitle, Description (UITextView?), possibly some image among the text.

I'm trying to make a design similar to the [iChemistry app](http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/8a/cf/5c/8acf5cc5-520c-be6d-de6a-26fda2775115/screen322x572.jpeg)

The problem is that TextView supports scrolling because it's already a child of UIScrollView. Second is that I got some issues with the vertical only, apparently UIScrollView is only enabling horizontal scrolling to my UITextView.

How can I display different objects and multiline text within only UIScrollView? (just like iChemistry app). I also checked its files in .app and it gets raw content from a .sqlite db, so it's not using HTML.

EDIT: Recommendations on doing it with TableView?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a UITableView.

Comment: Why is your description a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`?

Comment: I considered the UITableView option. What's the best way now to display really different kinds of cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. Do you want to enable Vertical Scroll to UITextView & disable Horizontal Scroll?

For other issues:

> 1. Try UITableView, use different custom cells.
>
>    Or
> 2. Simply, use UIView and increase scrollView.contentSize.

Here's how you use different custom cells in one UITableView:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
        if(indexPath.section==0)
        {
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
            FirstCustomCell *cell = (FirstCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            } 
           cell.textLabel.text= @"FirstCustomCellText";
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

            SecondCustomCell *cell = (SecondCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            } 
           cell.textLabel.text= @"SecondCustomCellText";
            return cell;
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm trying UITableView with different custom cells and I got a result. The problem now is, how can I have 2 different types of custom cell? I managed to do just one.

Comment: Use different custom cells for different sections like I have shown you above in answer. I have only used two custom cells in example, you can use any number of custom cells.

Comment: In that app I resolved my problem with another system (just a kind of cell with a label where I replaced some particular text with images, like @"... image.png ..." with the proper image, but this answer was really useful to me for another applicaiton! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try by taking UICollectionView in cell.

Comment: What's the advantage in using UICollectionView inside a cell?